# Hide and show input fields with onclick or similar function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple input fields. I only want one to show at a time. When the user is done entering information and hits next button it will hide the first input and show the second input. when they hit next again it will hide the second input and show the third input and so on. I've tried hiding the div and input fields directly  with hide()/show() JQuery functions but but can't seem to get them to work. Here's a basic example of the structure i'm using, any input is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Updated the JSBIN and sample code to the method i've tried to get working.

```
JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/wixiyaraxi/edit?html,output


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- // should be VISABLE at the start and be HIDDEN when Next button is clicked. -->
    <div id="test1">
    <input type="text" id="test1" class="form-control" placeholder="Input 1:">
    </div>

    <!-- // should be HIDDEN at the start and be VISABLE when Next button is clicked. -->
    <!-- // when the Next button is clicked a second time should be HIDDEN.-->
    <div id="test2">
    <input type="text" id="test2" class="form-control" placeholder="Input 2:">  
    </div>

    <!-- // should be hidden at the start and show when Next button is clicked a second time. -->
    <div id="test3">
    <input type="text" id="test3" class="form-control" placeholder="Input 3:">  
    </div>


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Next</button>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>

<script>

$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#test1").hide();
    $("#test2").show();
})
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include the JavaScript that you attempted to use. Please update your question to include this, otherwise it should be closed as [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, give your `<div>` input containers a class "input", hide everything but the first child in CSS. Once you have that in place, your button click handler can be as simple as: get the current visible .input div, hide it then show the next one

```
$(function() {
   $('button').on('click', function() {
      var $cur = $('div.input:visible');
      $cur.hide();
      $cur.next().show();
   });
});
```

Comment: this only hides visible inputs correct? it doesn't .show ones that start as hidden?(style="display:none")

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- // should be VISABLE at the start and be HIDDEN when Next button is clicked. -->
<div class="test1">
    <input type="text" id="test1" class="form-control" placeholder="Input 1:">
</div>

<!-- // should be HIDDEN at the start and be VISABLE when Next button is clicked. -->
<!-- // when the Next button is clicked a second time should be HIDDEN.-->
<div class="test2">
    <input type="text" id="test2" class="form-control" placeholder="Input 2:">  
</div>

<!-- // should be hidden at the start and show when Next button is clicked a second time. -->
<div class="test3">
    <input type="text" id="test3" class="form-control" placeholder="Input 3:">  
</div>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Next</button>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var i = 1;
        $(".form-control").each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $("#test" + i).show();

        $(".btn").click(function(){
            if(i < 3){
                i++;
            }
            $(".form-control").hide();
            $("#test" + i).show();
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```